# How change href value after window is loaded

Tags: javascript

Here is an a link with text:

```
 <a class="linkk" href="/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/"><p class="posttt">blablablabla</p></a>
```

JavaScript code to edit `href` property of all links

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var aEl = document.getElementsByClassName('linkk');
    for(var link in aEl) {
        link.href = "javascript:void(0)";
    }
};
 </script>
```

Not working. Why? example: `https://geburtstagsplanet.com/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/`

Answer (score 5):

Your for loop is wrong. The `for..in` loop is for enumerating the keys of an object, not items in an array. Replace your loop with:

```
var link;
for (var i = 0; i < aEl.length; i++) {
  link = aEl[i];
  link.href = "javascript:void(0)";
}
```

Comment: must i update so? please see:

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var aEl = document.getElementsByClassName('linkk');
   for (var i = 0; i < aEl.length; i++) {
  link = aEl[i];
  link.href = "javascript:void(0)";
}
};
 </script>

Comment: @InteressanteFakten: could you rephrase your question? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: can i completly delete a link after window is loaded?

Comment: Sure, `link.parentNode.removeChild(link)`. MDN has great documentation, you might want to look through that to see all the things you can do with DOM elements. Reference for `removeChild`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Answer (score 3):

You can use a for..of loop over the Array created by `Array.from(aEl)`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var aEl = document.getElementsByClassName('linkk');
    for(var link of Array.from(aEl)) {
        link.href = "javascript:void(0)";
    }
};
```

```html
<a class="linkk" href="/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/">
  <p class="posttt">blablablabla</p>
</a>
<a class="linkk" href="/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/">
  <p class="posttt">blablablabla</p>
</a>
<a class="linkk" href="/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/">
  <p class="posttt">blablablabla</p>
</a>
<a class="linkk" href="/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/">
  <p class="posttt">blablablabla</p>
</a>
<a class="linkk" href="/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/">
  <p class="posttt">blablablabla</p>
</a>
<a class="linkk" href="/allgemeinen/sfsdf-sd-d-d-fd/">
  <p class="posttt">blablablabla</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that `Array.from` and `for..of` require modern variants of JavaScript, so if you're targeting older browsers this won't work without transpilation/polyfills.

Answer (score 2):

If you `for..in` loop, change how you set the `href`.

```
if(aEl.hasOwnProperty(ele)) {
    aEl[ele].href = 'javascript:void(0)';
}
```

When you do the `for..in` loop, you are getting the `key` of the object returned by `document.getElementsByClassName('linkk');`, so using the `key` in this fashion gets you the `value`. Then you can set `href`.

Comment: I'd be careful with `for..in` because you may get keys that aren't related to indexes as well, so it's not guaranteed that `aEl[ele]` will be one of your hyperlinks.

Comment: @Jacob Edited to show wrapping in `hasOwnProperty()`.